# Is there a way to pipe ReadableStream<Uint8Array> into NextApiResponse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, next.js, node-fetch

I'd like to display Google Place Photos in my NextJS application. To GET these images from their specified URL an API key is needed, but at the same time, I do not want to expose this API key to the public.

My goal is to implement a NextJS API route that fetches and returns a specified image from Google Places Photos, while also being able to be accessed directly from an image tag like so:

```
<img src={`/api/photos/${place?.photos[0].photo_reference}`} alt='' />
```

I found a few different sources online that recommended I pipe the response stream from my google request directly to the response stream of the outgoing response like so:

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo
  &photo_reference=${id}
  &key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}`,
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(response);
    res.status(500).end();
    return;
  }

  response.body.pipe(res);
}
```

however as response.body is a ReadableStream, it does not have a .pipe() function. Instead it has .pipeTo() and .pipeThrough().

I then tried

```
response.body.pipeTo(res);
```

however, this also fails to work because res is a NextApiResponse rather than a WritableStream. Although I searched online, I haven't found out how to write to NextApiResponse similarly to WritableStreams.

Finally, I tried manually converting the response into a buffer and writing it to the NextApiResponse like so:

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo
  &photo_reference=${id}
  &key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}`,
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(response);
    res.status(500).end();
    return;
  }

  const resBlob = await response.blob();
  const resBufferArray = await resBlob.arrayBuffer();
  const resBuffer = Buffer.from(resBufferArray);

  const fileType = await fileTypeFromBuffer(resBuffer);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType?.mime ?? 'application/octet-stream');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', resBuffer.length);
  res.write(resBuffer, 'binary');
  res.end();
}
```

and while this completes the response, no image is displayed.

How can I directly pass the retrieved google places image from the server to the frontend so that it can be used by a  tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What worked for me was to simply cast the `response.body` of type `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` to a `NodeJS.ReadableStream` and then use the `pipe` function.

```
const readableStream = response.body as unknown as NodeJS.ReadableStream;
readableStream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I get "TypeError: readableStream.pipe is not a function". Are you using node-fetch? I'm using Node.js 18's built-in fetch, so perhaps that's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

One of the comments to the accepted answer points out that it doesn't work for Node.js's built-in `fetch` (available in Node.js >= 17.5). To make it work:

**Using Next.js's "nodejs" runtime**

```js
import {Readable} from 'stream';

// omitting handler code for readability

const nodeReadableStream = Readable.from(response.body);
nodeReadableStream.pipe(res);
```

**Using Next.js's "edge" runtime**

You can simply do:

```js
return Response(response.body)
```

Comment: I get `Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<any> | AsyncIterable<any>'.ts(2345)
` when trying this

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterating over values of the reader will do the job.
This doesn't require any hacks or whatsoever, and is as performant as other solutions.

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const image = await fetch("https://domain-to-your-cool-image")
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");

  if (!image.body) {
    res.end()
    return
  }

  const reader = image.body.getReader()
  while (true) {
    const result = await reader.read()
    if (result.done) {
      res.end()
      return
    }

    res.write(result.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. If you're using Vercel you can stream directly from the Edge. You can convert API route to use `experimental-edge` runtume

```
// pages/api/png.ts 

import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const config = {
  runtime: 'experimental-edge',
}

// Streamable content
const RESOURCE_URL =
  'https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/streams/png-transform-stream/png-logo.png'

export default async function handler(request: NextRequest) {
  const r = await fetch(RESOURCE_URL)

  const reader = r.body.getReader()

  const response = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read()

        // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
        if (done) {
          break
        }

        // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
        controller.enqueue(value)
      }

      // Close the stream
      controller.close()
      reader.releaseLock()
    },
  })

  return new Response(response)
}
```

2. Use [next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in the config (by paths or regex to pass only that id)
3. Use [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher) to match those url to handle rewrite, no need to transfer and stream